# Computational overhead of "SCALING FORWARD GRADIENT WITH LOCAL LOSSES"

Tags: deep-learning, backpropagation, research, gradient

The paper "[SCALING FORWARD GRADIENT WITH LOCAL LOSSES](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.03310.pdf)" discusses a new way of training deep neural networks called forward gradient learning. This method is different from the traditional backpropagation method. However, when applied to large networks, it can have high variance. The paper proposes some changes to the method to make it more practical for deep learning tasks. They suggest using perturbations to activations instead of weights to reduce variance. They also introduce a new architecture called LocalMixer that is better suited for local learning. The new approach performs well on standard deep learning tasks (MNIST and CIFAR-10) and outperforms other backpropagation-free algorithms on ImageNet.

**Question**: As the forward learning approach does not require the backpropagation pass, is it accurate to assume that forward learning (roughly speaking) achieves ~2x speedup in training compared with backpropagation, assuming all other parameters are the same such as the number of epochs, batch size .. etc?

I would get an answer to my question if I could run the code linked in the paper, I tried to run it but it failed giving the following error!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_mixer_supervised.py", line 2532, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train_mixer_supervised.py", line 2454, in main
    layer_sizes = get_layer_sizes(
  File "google-research/local_forward_gradient/mixer_lib.py", line 125, in get_layer_sizes
    num_tokens_ = num_tokens_ // (downsample[blk]**2)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Note**: I contacted the corresponding author of the paper and I still have not gotten any response to my question or the error reported above.